# How to force fail a java regex?

Tags: java, regex

In java, you can text a regex by doing

```
"mystring".matches("myregex")
```

But is there a certain regex you can use, that will make `matches` function evaluate to a `false`? It needs to work for all cases (i.e. no matter what string you test it with).

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want this? If you've already made the assumption that the regex must always be false, what's stopping you from simply using a boolean?

Comment: probably because he wants to pass it to some (library) function calling `matches()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you would need this, but this should do the trick

```
"mystring".matches("(?!)")
```